# how to enable firestore persistence through web?

Tags: node.js, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I'm New in **FIRESTORE** . I don't know how to enable persistence throught web. In firestore API they gave some steps, but still i didnt understand

```
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    saveButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var config = { 
apiKey: "AIzaSyCuUm2LH0OEeojblAYHN52RFGogHEcnsDY",
        authDomain: "cloud-7aac4.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://cloud-7aac4.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "cloud-7aac4",
        storageBucket: "cloud-7aac4.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "605897634030",
        presistence:"true"};
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    /*enable persistence*/
    firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
      .then(function() {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var docRef = db.doc('samples/alovelace');
     docRef.set({
        first: 'Ada',
        last: 'Lovelace',
        born: 1815
    });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
          if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
              // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
              // in one tab at a a time.
              // ...
          } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
              // The current browser does not support all of the
              // features required to enable persistence
              // ...
          }
      });
```

And also is there is any possible to enable persistence using nodejs sdk without web?

Please point me to some working samples.

Comment: The Node.js SDK for Cloud Firestore does not support disk persistence.

Comment: Aside from that: what isn't clear about the code you shared? What doesn't work about it? It's much easier to help if you describe what you've done with the code and what didn't work. Or even better: add `console.log` statements that print the thing that you are asking (or confused) about.